# How can I upgrade my Ruby Gems to the latest version "safely"?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, upgrade, package

Is there any way that I can upgrade my Ruby Gems, and if it doesn't work (on what I'm upgrading them for), than rollback the changes?

Answer (score 2):

You need install rubygems in other directory of your previous version. After you can change all link to rubygems to this new version.

You can use too rvm. It's really simple and it's allways with latest rubygems. If you don't want it. just delete the .rvm directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade RubyGems as normal, if it messes up, just download the last version and run `sudo ruby setup.rb`. http://rubygems.org/pages/download

If you do run into problems, the RubyGems team would love to hear about it: http://help.rubygems.org